# Border-box breaks the container of the responsive image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a `<div>`, with fixed height and padding. The border-box property is applied on the whole page. Inside the `<div>` I have an `<img>` with `max-width:100%`, and `max-height:100%` properties. My problem is the container is wider than excepted (I think because of the `padding`).

What is the best solution to add `padding` around the image without breaking the design OR how to fix it?

I saved it to JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/4eo6bebj/) and I also added it to my question.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#responsive-image {
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    padding:15px;
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="responsive-image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/">
</div>
```

[image]

Update: The problem is visible in Firefox.

Comment: How wide do you want the container to be? It is currently correctly maintaining the image aspect ratio based on the height that you've specified.

Comment: You mention that your images in inside an `a` tag but in the example code you given it's inside a `div`.  Is this correct?

Comment: The width is depends from the height, but it adds extra pixels on the right.

Comment: My bad, I modify the question.

Comment: I would like a red box without extra space on the right.

Comment: @Bender I updated the question with an image, please check it.

Comment: @user1452062 you have to use `min-width:100%` for `img` element. check Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/4eo6bebj/28/

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `padding` from the `div` and add it into inner elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/6ux1wjLc/

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#responsive-image {
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
}
#responsive-image * {
    padding: 10px;
}
img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="responsive-image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" />
</div>
```

Comment: I know the syntax. My problem is the div is bigger than the image (the space on the right side is bigger). I removed the side paddings, so probably you will see my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/yuuwzs1z/1/

I updated the question with an image, @sdcr please check it.

Comment: The `div` doesn't have fixed width, so it should be smaller. When I remove the `border-box` property it's ok, but I need `border-box` :)

http://jsfiddle.net/yuuwzs1z/3/

Comment: @user1452062 you can reset border-box to content-box (default value) on that div only if you want - http://jsfiddle.net/yuuwzs1z/4/

Comment: I would like to reduce the size with the padding, so the available height will be smaller, what affects the image. I would like to use these properties but get rid of the extra space on the right.

Comment: @user1452062 I finally figured out you must see the extra white space on Firefox only, see the updated answer if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the update, but I have more content in the div, so I need padding. I don't want to add padding for every element.

Comment: @user1452062 that is the best i could do, updated. I doubt it if it's possible like you said, but good luck.